# screen mirroring is not working in iPad 7th generation (using reflector on MacBook)

Tags: macos, big-sur, screen-sharing

I am trying to mirror my iPad screen to MacBook Air using reflector (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyEtm2WMBZ0&t=540s). Both have same wifi connection.

I am seeing the following:

[image]

How do I fix this issue?

I do see that my iPad and MacBook are linked somehow. If I open a photo or a file in ipad, and look for sharing it shows airdrop option and in that I can see my MacBook name. If I click that, the file is sent to my MacBook.

I am using Mac OS Big Sur version 11.4

Comment: Airdrop ignores your connected wifi network, so it's not relevant to this AFAIK. Have you tried this on another Wifi network to see if that might be causing the problem?

Comment: @ToddDabney I tried connecting to another wifi. It did not help.

Comment: Is the iPad updated to the latest software as well? Apple does not generally do a great job of backwards compatibility, so updating to the latest OS on both may solve this.

Comment: @ToddDabney It is updated. Not sure why it is not working